# Blank Zebra print ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing, zebra-printers, sharp

I'm trying to print a text/barcode on a Zebra printer with an ASP.NET web application.

My code is:

```
PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
ps.PrinterName = "zebra";

List<byte> page = new List<byte>();
page.AddRange(ZPLCommands.ClearPrinter(ps));

page.AddRange(ZPLCommands.TextWrite(1, 1, ElementDrawRotation.NO_ROTATION, 1, "Teste"));

page.AddRange(ZPLCommands.PrintBuffer(1));
new SpoolPrinter(ps).Print(page.ToArray());
```

The printer throws the paper but its blank.

Can you have any idea to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably printing but outside the print area of the paper. Check you printers setting (margins etc) and change the values for x and y coordinates around until your print fits on the paper.

Also make sure you are using the correct printer driver.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the you should see your template first, 
use **Zebra Designer** then convert the design into text file that contains **ZPL commands**.

You can indicate the actual paper size on **Zebra Designer**.